# How to print out a recursion method?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class RecursionPracticeProgram {
    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();

public String backString(String s){
    s = reader.readLine("String: ");
    if(s.length()==0)
        return s;

    System.out.println(backString(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0));   

    return backString(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);


} 

public void run(){
    backString("Fox");
}
```

I am doing some recursion work but am having trouble printing it out. I think I have the code correct for reversing a string but when I go to run the program it just builds and doesn't actually print anything out. How do I print it out properly?

Comment: Why do you immediately discard the parameter passed to your method?  What do you think `reader.readLine("String: ")` does?

Comment: I forgot that I put that there. I took it out but it still didn't run properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure to only read once and you call your method at all.
Just do it like this:

```
public class RecursionPracticeProgram {
  public void run() {
    String input = reader.readLine("String: ");
    KeyboardReader reader = new KeyboardReader();
    System.out.println(reader.backstring(input));
  }

  public String backString(String s){
    if(s.length()==0)
        return s;
    System.out.println(backString(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0));   
    return backString(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my code to include that but it still didn't print. Am I supposed to put something in my main method?

Comment: @clopez Yes, of course you need to have something in your `main` method. It is where program execution starts. How should it go to the `run` method if the `main` method is not calling it?

Comment: I updated my answer - There were a few other issues.

Comment: You can't call methods like `println` outside of a method like you show here.